# Wpf and Winform application not opening

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2015

we have wpf application, we installed it on client system, but it's not opening on double click of desktop shortcut or .exe file. But this application working fine for other systems.

And one more check I've done is I made hello world wpf and winform projects, debug and try to open these .exe file in client machine, same probelm.
But hello world console application is working fine.

Please find client system details:
Windows 10, 64 bit

Our project built using VS 2015, 
target is :.NETFramework,Version=v4.5

So, what could be the problem?

Comment: You can find the error details from Event Viewer.

Comment: We checked in event viewer, it showing below error :

Comment: Application: SMP_WINDOWS.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at System.Windows.Application..cctor()

Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
   at System.Windows.Application..ctor()
   at SMP_WINDOWS.App.Main()

Comment: Faulting application name: SMP_WINDOWS.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x57a32386
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.873, time stamp: 0x58da048a
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000bdb18
Faulting process id: 0x45c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2b426fc924705
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\EAFT Technologies\ETOOS\SMP_WINDOWS.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 46864695-9ba2-4063-a1d2-e9104dafcaf9
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: You need to debug the source code of SMP_Windows.exe. The exception is thrown from the very first few lines of the program, so you wouldn't even see the window showing up

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue few days before as my application was opening fine in windows 7, 8 & 8.1, but was unable to run on windows 10. After searching a lot i figured out that build i was generating from Spoon studio which didn't support windows 10 as it was not upgraded. I used latest spoon studio and my app worked fine at windows 10. For your application verify how you are creating installer & giving to client. Verify that you are using any third party installer which is not upgraded or does not support windows 10. Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: We have used Visual studio for creating .msi, it installed correctly but in 1 client machine only its not opening..

Comment: Try running application on safe mode. Also please verify that in few machines antivirus block the application, try to pause anti-virus and than try to run application.

Comment: Any luck in running app?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this issue is caused by incompatibility between 32bit application and 64bit Operating System. So I would suggest you try to set the platform of your application from x86 to Any CPU in Configuration Manager in Visual Studio.

Or

Try running your application in elevation mode.

Comment: Platform of the application to 'Any CPU'.. tried .. same issue

Comment: Could potentially be the version of .NET on your client machine being different from that of your forms application.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it is an `FileNotFoundException` thrown from the App.xmal.cs. Maybe a static field (so the method is `.cctor`) that is initialized by loading a file that does not exist on that machine.

> Application: SMP_WINDOWS.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException at System.Windows.Application..cctor() Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException at System.Windows.Application..ctor() at SMP_WINDOWS.App.Main()

Without debugging the source code, the "possible causes" are merely wild guesses.